# Training Tensorflow with 200 Images only

Tags: image, tensorflow

Folks,

I need to train only one object or a class (example: an elephant) using Tensorflow, Can I use only 100 or 200 Images to train using Tensorflow.

Can you please let me know.

Thanks
Guru

Comment: Training with a neural network? I ask because Tensorflow is just the computational library, it is not a specific type of training. What do you want the classified to do? Just recognise different classes or only one class?

Comment: what are you training ? A classifier ? A detector ? In both cases it should be possible if your dataset is easy (you can see the elephants very well, they look a lot alike between them, they are always seen from the same angle...), and hard otherwise. It is very hard to judge precisely without trying; but it's probably not enough. A detector will be harder to train than a classifier (only saying if it is a picture of an elephant or not)

Comment: I am training a wild animal detector .... with 200 images each ... using TensorFlow ...  I am using some 15 different wild animal classes ....